# what is the meaning of 'to leave somebody's side"?

Tags: meaning

I found this phrase in some poetry. The lines are as follows,

> ...
>       a rose on the other side of the room,
>       side of the rose on the wall of the other room inside,
>       the side of the slide that opens on the wound
>       I leave her side on a rose of blood
>       ...

another one is like,

> I will never leave your side.
>       Even if you push me away, and tell me it’s not right.
>       These are times and moments, where love takes a stand.
>       ...

I want to know the possible meaning of the phrase "to leave someone's side".

Comment: You are next to someone. You leave them. You leave their side

Comment: Questions like this one – that is, questions asking for a basic explanation of a commonly used expression – would be a better fit at the companion [ell.se] site.

Comment: @mplungjan True. But the saying is also used metaphorically. I could be by someone's side by supporting them even though they may be on the opposite side of the world. :)

Comment: Sure. Still the same meaning - next to someone metaphorically - leave them physically or metaphorically - same as leaving them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means, "You are next to someone. You leave them. You leave their side."

It can also mean, "You are not supporting emotionally."
You can say he left my side. Which means he left me as well as he is not supporting me anymore.